# To be in the center or to be at the center

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-in

- I want to be in the center of the change.
- I want to be at the center of the change.

In the context, the statement makes that I want to be at the center of the changing society, I want to play an important role.

Which preposition do I need?

Comment: I don't think you need a preposition there at all.

Comment: *I want to be the center of change.* The second definite article can be skipped as well when talking about *the changing society.*

Comment: @Kris If you don't include a preposition it becomes *I want to be the centre of change* - meaning, you want to be the very central pivot. *In* or *at the centre* would include for your being part of a collective centre. *They are the six people who are at the centre of the Clinton campaign*. *Ken Clarke is one of the people at the centre of the campaign to remain in the single market*.

Comment: @WS2 Which is what I'd meant.

Answer (score 2):

At means place, position. So I'd say **at the centre of change**, or like you phrase it *"**at** the centre of the changing society"*.

In means inside a whole or a context, or a situation, a phenomenon maybe. So I'd say **in change**, **in society** etc.

I think one should follow his physical understanding in such things.

Answer (score 1):

When I say **at the centre**, I think of a particular point, like the centre of a circle. On the other hand, **in the centre** gives a vague idea of some area surrounding the centre. So, if you're the main figure who is causing the change, it should be **at** the centre and if you're just a part of it, like say a member of a political campaign, you can use **in**. However, this interpretation may be too literal... I personally think **at the centre** should be correct for a more figurative understanding.